# Low boundary of $\mathcal W$ function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Picture below is from Topping's Lectures on Ricci flow.

I don't understand the red line. From Lemma 8.1.8, I can get that  $\mathcal W (g,f,\tau)$ has low boundary for any compatible $f,g,\tau$. But how to get $\mathcal W$ has uniform low boundary on $(0,\tau_0]$ ?

PS: I asked the problem in [ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339666/low-boundary-of-mathcal-w-function) without answer. Therefore, I ask here for help.

> [image]

Comment: See chapter 6 pages 234-235 of Chow et al https://doi.org/10.1090/surv/135